# Woocommerce template not overriding

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to override a woocommerce plugin but somehow it wont work.
In my custom theme I added the following in functions.php

```
function add_theme_wc_support() {
    add_theme_support('woocommerce');
    add_theme_support('woocommerce-composite-products');
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'add_theme_wc_support');
```

The directory for my template:

```
theme\templates\woocommerce-composite-products\single-product\template-file.php
```

I edited the template but nothing happened. I also tried to change the folder "woocommerce-composite-products" to just "woocommerce" but nothing.

My functions.php only contains the "add_theme_wc_support" function, so there cant be any conflicts.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Not all plugins let you do this, i learned it the hard way. Check the file in the plugin, maybe you missed something, usually there is a comment that explains how to 'template override'.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast it says: 'yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/component-single-page.php'.

Comment: Which is why im so confused as to why it wouldnt work

Comment: but in your question you said that this is your directory = theme\templates\woocommerce-composite-products\single-product\template-file.php.
the directory needs to be theme/woocommerce/single-product/component-single-page.php

Comment: @Buttered_Toast ya, I tried that too. I tried both and it doesnt work. Just now I switched it back to woocommerce and nothing happens.

Comment: could you provide a screenshot of your wordpress theme editor, im sure that you missed something.

Comment: It should be in **themes** *folder* > **"your active child theme or theme"** *folder* > **woocommerce** *folder* > **single-product** folder > **component-single-page.php** *php file*…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the comment you provided about how the plugin wants you to override the template your file path should look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If need to overwrite **woocommerce** functionality, You have to create woocommerce folder in your active theme and  duplicate the file.

Ex:

Your Theme is **Twentytwenty** you have to do themes/twentytwenty/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php